# cant add POST content to mysql database

Tags: php, mysql

```
<?php

require "config.php";

/*
CREATE TABLE  `addnews` (
 `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY ,
 `auther` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL ,
 `title` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL ,
 `content` LONGTEXT NOT NULL
) ENGINE = MYISAM ;
*/

$a = $_POST['author'];
$t = $_POST['title'];
$c = $_POST['content'];

if(isset($_POST["add"]) and $_POST["add"] == "news"){
    $insert = mysql_query('INSERT INTO addnews 
    (author,title,content)
    VALUES
    ("$a","$t","$c")') or die("error");
    if (isset($insert )){
        echo "<h3>Done</h3>";
    }
};

echo "
<form action='".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."' method='post'>
Author : <input type='text' name='author' /><br>
Title : <input type='text' name='title' /><br>
Content : <textarea name='content'></textarea>
<input type='submit' value='Add news' />
<input type='hidden' name='add' value='news' />
</form>
";


mysql_close($connectdb);
?>
```

i am getting error from this statment i think

```
if(isset($_POST["add"]) and $_POST["add"] == "news"){
    $insert = mysql_query('INSERT INTO addnews 
    (author,title,content)
    VALUES
    ("$a","$t","$c")') or die("error happend while trying to add information to database");
    if (isset($insert )){
        echo "<h3>Done</h3>";
    }
};
```

### output is : error happend while trying to add information to database

and no problem with config.php file (the file that connect to database)
i am using phpmyadmin

Comment: Read this, please: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php?lq=1

Comment: i dont care about security for now
this is my first sql code i am just learning

Comment: Especially in that case I'd suggest to learn it the _right_ way from the beginning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. strings in sql are surrounded by ' (single quote) , not by " (double quote)
2. strings in php will act two ways

   1. those in ' (single quote) will write literally as tyou typed them ($a stays $a - not $a value)
   2. those in " (double quote) will interpret values inside - so $a will be substituted with $a's value
3. when failing DB operation - it is usually useful to see what was wrong - use [mysql_error](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php) for that

Answer (score 0):

Use && instead of the actual word and:

```
if(isset($_POST["add"]) && $_POST["add"] == "news"){
    $insert = mysql_query("INSERT INTO addnews 
    (author,title,content)
    VALUES
    ('$a','$t','$c')") or die("error happend while trying to add information to database");
    if (isset($insert )){
        echo "<h3>Done</h3>";
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go try this one

```
if(isset($_POST["add"]) and $_POST["add"] == "news"){
    $insert = mysql_query('INSERT INTO addnews 
    (author,title,content)
    VALUES
    ("'. $a .'","'. $t .'","'. $c .'")') or die("error happend while trying to add information to database");
    if (isset($insert )){
        echo "<h3>Done</h3>";
    }
};
```

used `"'. $a .'"` instead `"$a"`.

Comment: still the sam problem :(

Comment: you sure you're receiving post values correctly, try `var_dump($_POST)`

Answer (score 0):

I think the query statement is wrong, 
Double quotes inside the single quotes is not valid in php.
So you will change the quotes in query like below code,

```
$insert = mysql_query("INSERT INTO addnews 
    (author,title,content)
    VALUES
    ('$a','$t','$c')") or die("error");
```

try this..:-)

Comment: $insert = mysqli_query("INSERT INTO addnews 
    (author,title,content)
    VALUES
    ('".$a."','".$t."','".$c."')") or die("error");

Comment: try mysqli_query() instead of mysql_query()

Answer (score 0):

Please do the correction in your code like as follow:

```
$insert = mysql_query("INSERT INTO addnews 
    (author,title,content)
    VALUES
    ('$a','$t','$c')") or die(mysql_error($link));//Where $link mysql resource object
```

You will get the answer why Mysql not inserting your data.